# Parsing RIPE Allocations RegEx

Tags: php, regex, ip-address

I'm working on project where I need to parse the RIPE allocations database (ftp://ftp.ripe.net/ripe/stats/membership/alloclist.txt) into a database.

I need to grab out every single member, so I need it to match everything between xx. and \n\nxx. where x is any lowercase letter.

Here's a few lines of the file:

```
ad.andorpac
    Servei de Telecomunicacions d'Andorra 

    19960627    194.158.64.0/19 ALLOCATED PA
    20050104    85.94.160.0/19  ALLOCATED PA
    20061117    91.187.64.0/19  ALLOCATED PA
    20091124    109.111.96.0/19 ALLOCATED PA
    20120925    185.4.52.0/22   ALLOCATED PA
    20110722    2a02:8060::/31

ae.absl-me
    Asia Broadcast Satellite Ltd (Middle East) 

    20110321    31.47.88.0/21   ALLOCATED PA

ae.adac
    Abu Dhabi Airports Company PJSC 

    20120402    37.218.224.0/21 ALLOCATED PA
```

I'm not a RegEx expert, can anyone provide these expressions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like:

```
 preg_match_all("/[a-z]{2}\..*?\n\n[a-z]{2}\./s", $text, $matches)
```

Should work.

This assumes your description of the problem is accurate!  If it isn't, you can expect this regex to prove to be very brittle.

(ie: undesirable instance of `\n\n[a-z]{2}\.` occurs, you want the first 3 characters of the next entry included in each match, two new lines will always be present between your records and they will be adjacent, without any other character between including any whitespace, etc.).

Okay, I would guess you don't *really* want to get the end "xx." as part of a match, so the alternative would be to use a lookahead for it, like:

```
     preg_match_all("/[a-z]{2}\..*?\n\n(?=[a-z]{2}\.)/s", $text, $matches)
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a very elaborated regex to parse this. You can just split by the delimiter, and then parse each entry:

```
// $string contains the text
$entries = explode("\n\n", $string);
for($i=0; $i < sizeof($entries); $i+=2){
    parse_header($entries[$i]));
    parse_entries($entries[$i+1]);
}
```

The "header" is like "ad.andorpac\nServei de Telecomunicacions(...)" so it should be pretty easy to parse. To parse the entries, you can split them by "\n" and then process each with a regex to split the fields by spaces:

```
function parse_entry($entries){
    $strings = explode("\n", $entries);
    foreach($strings as $s){
        preg_match("/(?P<number>\d+)\s+(?P<addr>[\d\.\/]+)\s+(?P<str1>\w+)\s+(?P<str2>\w+)/",   
            $s, $result);
    // You can then access then the results
    echo $results["addr"]; // prints "185.4.52.0/22"
    }       
}
```

This is not a full working answer but should address the majority of your problems. You may also need to use `trim` function to remove spaces at the start/end of the matched strings.

#### Edit

A quick explanation of the regex:

```
(?P<number>\d+) => matches one or more digits, and stores them in the "number" index
\s+ => matches one or more spaces and ignores them
(?P<addr>[\d\.\/]+) => matches the network address (one or more digits, dots or slashes)
\s+ => same
(?P<str1>\w+) => matches the first string ("ALLOCATED")
\s+ =>
(?P<str2>\w+) => matches the 2nd string
```